# Completing s 3/8 time signature

Tags: theory, terminology, time-signatures

[image]

I am trying to figure out the incomplete rests. I think for the first bar line there will be the eighth rest. I am not too sure about the next one but I think it will be 2 * eighth rest. Any hints or directions appreciated

[image]

And then in this one, there will be one-half rest in both the parts right?

Comment: This question suggests a lack of understanding of the relationship between eighth notes and sixteenth notes. I recommend reviewing some basic music theory material. When the relationship is understood, the answer to this exercise should be clear. Another option would be to post in more detail how you came to conclude (incorrectly) that a dotted eighth rest is needed in the first measure. That would allow someone here to explain whatever knowledge might be missing.

Comment: Oh Sorry I mean eighth rest for the first part and then two eight rest for the 2nd part. Would that be right? @Aaron

Comment: Yep. You've got it.

Comment: Are these homework questions?

Comment: No, I am interested in learning music and taking an online course these are just follow up questions @ToddWilcox

Comment: @Aaron is the second question also right?

Comment: Swaraj - it looks like you are making your way through a course - but perhaps need to look at the fundamentals first. If the course you are taking doesn't include those, I'd suggest you take a less advanced course first. Asking the homework questions here will not help you learn your course materials.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the comments you have part one figured out, that is you have to show a total of 3 eighths, rests or notes in each bar and 2 sixteenths equal one eighth. From there it is simple math.

As for part 2, you are on the right track mathematically, both bars are missing a half note, or 2 beats. The thing to take into consideration is that time signatures with a multiple of 3 in the top position are grouped in threes of the bottom number value. That means that 6/4 is two groups of 3 quarter notes in one bar. Taking that into consideration and also looking at the spacing of the notes in bar 1, rather than a half note rest either at the beginning or end of the measure, the right choice is a quarter rest at the beginning and another at the end of the bar. This will clearly show the division of the two groups of 3 quarter notes. Bar 2 is more obvious, a half note rest at the end of the bar will make this complete and correct. The half rest could also be before the quarter note as well but the note spacing seems to favor it after the quarter note.

Comment: That 2nd bar (6/4) could even have a crotchet rest either side of the crotchet note - there's space. Bet one of the 3 choices would be marked wrong, though. Be interesting to see!

Comment: @Tim Absolutely, the spacing of the existing notes supports that idea, good call!